# How to place an ad popup like scene in andengine

Tags: andengine, ads, scene

I want to start placing ads in my andengine game and an ad to appear just before my result display screen (for example fruit ninja). Since My result screen is a scene and not an activity, I want an ad to popup after my game play and just before results and on button click the ad disappears. I think there is a class called popupscene, but i am not sure if that is to be used. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I made an example using the GLES1 version of the engine:
https://github.com/zfoley/AndengineAdmobLayoutExample

The main thing is to use a LayoutGameActivity instead of a BaseGameActivity. 
LayoutGame activity supports having additional views in addition to the GLSurfaceView.

Once you have that going, its pretty simple to implement the admob API or whatever ad service you are using. In my example I use admob.

Comment: Thanks for the reply although i implemented admob using LayoutGameActivity. My problem is that i want a popup that contains ads and not ads on my main game activity. I hope your are understanding what i am asking. For example in fruit ninja, before displaying result, there is popup which contains ads.

Comment: Then you might just want to use a custom dialog where you put your admob view (and anything else you want to display) inside.

Comment: @Swati Rawat - you're going to have to be flexible. You can only have one instance of andengine running. And ads will always be in a separate view, either adjacent to or above the andengine view. So to make the add appear, and the popup scene too, you will need to manage those as separate entities.